# Is there no create_or_update for Azure Python SDK for provisioning Storage Accounts?

Tags: python, azure

I'm using the Azure Python SDK to provision resources in Azure.  I see that for resource groups and key vaults, the api has `create_or_update` methods, but for storage accounts, I can only find a `create` method.  Right now things are provisioning ok initially, but I'm interested in testing out how they *update* resources which were previously provisioned.  Am I missing something or is there no option to call a create_or_update for storage accounts?

Thanks much!

Comment: Can you provide a link of the SDK you're using?

Comment: Hello @IvanYang.  This is the SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-storage/azure.mgmt.storage.storagemanagementclient?view=azure-python Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [`update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-storage/azure.mgmt.storage.v2019_06_01.operations.storageaccountsoperations?view=azure-python#update-resource-group-name--account-name--parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) operation available for storage accounts. From the documentation link:

> The update operation can be used to update the SKU, encryption, access
>   tier, or tags for a storage account. It can also be used to map the
>   account to a custom domain. Only one custom domain is supported per
>   storage account; the replacement/change of custom domain is not
>   supported. In order to replace an old custom domain, the old value
>   must be cleared/unregistered before a new value can be set. The update
>   of multiple properties is supported. This call does not change the
>   storage keys for the account. If you want to change the storage
>   account keys, use the regenerate keys operation. The location and name
>   of the storage account cannot be changed after creation.

```
update(resource_group_name, account_name, parameters, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config)
```

Comment: Thank very much @Gaurav Mantri-AIS!  That is just what I was looking for.